# OpenCOR, "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb""

Tags: 16.04, qt

I'm trying to install [OpenCor](http://www.opencor.ws/)

When I try to launch it I got this error message :

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have found lot page on internet and some post, but nothing solved my problem....

I using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**EDIT** :

I have try to :

```
sudo apt-get install xcb
```

Which was already satified, :

```
xcb is already the newest version (2.4-4.3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

I tried almost everything proposed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without) and have no PPAs installed.

**EDIT 2**

The command :  `sudo apt upgrade`

return :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and still have the same problem with `OpenCOR` and the little script from @Fabby still do not give output at all...

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix it?  Have you tried simply installing xcb `sudo apt install xcb`  What error messages are you getting when you try to install the package?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1027465/edit) your question and give us more details.

Comment: yes of course, but I will edit my post

Comment: I am running Xubuntu 16.04.  I just downloaded and I ran the OpenCOR application and it ran without a problem.  Unfortunately I am unable to duplicate your issue, so all I can do is guess as to what might be causing it.  So, I won't be much help there.   I also didn't have to install OpenCOR, I just ran it from the `OpenCOR-2018-04-23-Linux/bin` folder and it ran fine.  I am sorry I am not much more help.

Comment: @Terrance I have tried to do the same... but I've got this error message. I understand that this problem is not specific to OpenCOR, but couldn't find solution...

Comment: What's the output of [this little script](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NnqVFbNcvk/) ???

Comment: @Fabby, I edited my post. thx

Comment: @Fabby, sorry understood now. there is no output at all from the script you give me...

Comment: OK, so no PPAs. I'll edit that in.  Does it work after you do a `sudo apt upgrade`? (as there are 18 packages waiting)  if no: what's the output of that command?

Comment: @Fabby I still have no result...

Comment: @Dadep  Does it work after you do a `sudo apt upgrade`? (as there are 18 packages waiting) if no: what's the output of that command?  Please [edit] your question to add the output.  Don't put it here in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further and N0rbert has posted an answer that looks to be working. So +1 to the question, take it up with N0rbert in chat. Desculpe / Je m'excuse...

Comment: @Fabby thanks a lot/muito obrigado/merci beaucoup. I learn many things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stable [OpenCOR 0.5](http://www.opencor.ws/downloads/index.html) works on clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.opencor.ws/downloads/0.5/OpenCOR-0-5-Linux.tar.gz
tar -xf OpenCOR-0-5-Linux.tar.gz
cd OpenCOR-0-5-Linux/
./OpenCOR
```

but shows warning on  launch:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1: symbol _ZTTNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

You can remove these messages with

```
sudo apt-get install glib-networking
```

But it shows *Error: illegal value* in the interface:

[image: OpenCOR 0.5 on Ubuntu Xenial]

I'm not familiar with this program, so I do not known is it critical or not.

--

Also it seems that [Latest snapshot](http://www.opencor.ws/downloads/index.html) version works out the box on
clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

You can proceed with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.opencor.ws/downloads/snapshots/2018-04-23/OpenCOR-2018-04-23-Linux.tar.gz
tar -xf OpenCOR-2018-04-23-Linux.tar.gz
cd OpenCOR-2018-04-23-Linux/
./OpenCOR
```

Then its GUI window was opened:

[image: OpenCOR snapshot on 16.04 LTS]

Comment: Thanks for your help, the latest snapshot version works but I still have the same  problem for OpenCOR 0.5...When I  do `./OpenCOR` I get the error describr in my post.

Comment: I have installed HWE on my 16.04 LTS, I can confirm error about *xcb* with v0.5 on it. It seems that you have two options: remove HWE (downgrade xserver) or use latest snapshot.